# upload multiple files in django

Tags: django

I am new to django, I am trying to upload more than one file from the browser and store them somewhere in computer storage but I am not storing them successfully with this code please help me out to find my mistake or improvements that I can do. Thanks in advance to help.

**views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    # Create your views here.

    def Form(request):
        return render(request, "index/form.html", {})

    def Upload(request):
        for count, x in enumerate(request.FILES.getlist("files")):
            def process(f):
                with open('/Users/benq/djangogirls/upload/media/file_' + str(count), 'wb+') as destination:
                    for chunk in f.chunks():
                        destination.write(chunk) 
            process(x)
        return HttpResponse("File(s) uploaded!")
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from index import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^form/$', views.Form),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.Upload)
]
```

**form.html**

```
<form method="post" action="../upload/" entype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="files" multiple />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything that's wrong with your code, any stack trace or unexpected behaviors could help debug it.

Comment: I am not getting any file in my storage

Comment: in my computer storage path that is given here /Users/benq/djangogirls/upload/media/

Comment: any alternate would also be appreciated

Comment: also, `enctype` is written with a typo (without `c`) so the browser defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, resulting in the file content not being included in the HTTP request body, thus server-side code cannot see it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

my model to save Document

```
class Document(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField('Document', upload_to='mydocs/')

  @property
  def filename(self):
     name = self.file.name.split("/")[1].replace('_',' ').replace('-',' ')
     return name
  def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('myapp:document-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

you can try a django create view in my code i use this DocumentCreateView

```
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
   model = Document
   fields = ['file']

   def form_valid(self, form):
     obj = form.save(commit=False)
     if self.request.FILES:
        for f in self.request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            obj = self.model.objects.create(file=f)

   return super(DocumentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

my form html file

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_file').attr("multiple","true");

  })
 </script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">{% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.file }}
 <input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Answer from official django documentation**

```
 file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Comment: This is what I use and works fine un Django==4.1.1 but it is not supported anymore in Django==4.2.1

Answer (score 3):

Just an update from Django 3.2 and above. According to docs you have to:

> If you want to upload multiple files using one form field, set the multiple HTML attribute of field’s widget:

```
from django import forms

class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

> Then override the post method of your FormView subclass to handle multiple file uploads:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import FileFieldForm

class FileFieldView(FormView):
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'  # Replace with your template.
    success_url = '...'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                ...  # Do something with each file.
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the multi uploads portion in the create view here: [Django Class based UpdateView with Form for Multiple Uploaded Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61903021/10150959) , however, now the update get function is what I am currently stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

As @dnet pointed out. The mistake is in your `HTML` in the `form` tag. If you don't specify `enctype` manually, the files will never get sent out (tested even with latest browser and django 4.2). Unfortunately for you, you didn't close the `<form>` and you have a spelling mistake in `enCtype`.

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="posts" multiple>
    <button type="submit">Import</button>
</form>
```

```py
# in your views.py
def upload_file(request):
   for file in request.FILES.getlist('posts'):
       process(file)  # file is an instance of django.core.files.File
   return redirect('app:wherever')
```