# Multiple file uploads with Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to write an app that can handle uploading multiple files at a time. I had the app working for a single file upload, but adding a loop to process a list of files hasn't worked yet.

```
#models.py
class image(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='default')
```

Form:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = image
    fields = ('image',)
    widgets = {'image': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}),} # Added to allow multiple file selections in one dialog box
```

And relevant part of `views.py`:

```
def image_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
            formI = ImageForm(request.POST, f, instance=image())
            if formI.is_valid():
                fs = formI.save(commit=False)
                fs.filename = f
                fs.user = request.user
                fs.save()
```

(There's other stuff going on in the view, but it currently breaks before that).

The result is the error: 
`AttributeError: 'TemporaryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'`
from the line: `if formI.is_valid():`

I originally had `formI = ImageForm(request.POST, f, instance=image())` with `request.FILES` instead of `f`, and it seems likely that change is what's breaking this. What should I have instead of those two options? `request.FILES` results in only one image out of the selected being uploaded.

What is the correct object to pass to `ImageForm`?

Using Python 3.6.8 and Django 2.2.4

Edit: I've seen other SO questions about multiple file uploads, including the suggested duplicate, but none made clear to me what object `ImageForm` needs (rather than `f` in my example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload multiple files in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525188/upload-multiple-files-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Use django `formsets. That should solve your problem and also take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006994/how-to-upload-multiple-images-to-a-blog-post-in-django/34007383#34007383) for complete implementation.

Comment: I didn't know much about formsets, but after a little reading, it seems like they allow multiple instances of a form on a page, is that true? I'm looking to upload multiple files through one form.

Comment: @Bird Did you check this [link](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload) in comments ? there is only one model to handle uploading images in one place