# passing Multiple File name from Django templates to views in python

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i need to pass the file name from Django template to views.py . It works fine if i am passing one file name ,but when it comes to multiple file  i am able to select multiple files but in views.py only the first file is showing . BTW i am new to Django . Please correct me if i am going worng.

Html code :

```
   <form method="post" action="add" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
           {% csrf_token%}
          <div class="form-group files">
            <label>Upload Your File </label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="num1[]" 
            multiple/>
              <button type="submit" class="form-control" >Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Python code :

```
def add(request):

val1 = request.POST['num1']
print(val1)
```

Expect result :  [File1 , File2]

list or dictionary is fine

Actual result : file1
 #needed both file names

Comment: Are you uploading multiple files by using shift+select?

Comment: @JayVasant yes i am selecting using shift+select

Comment: Can you post your what's coming in your request, or you can refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525188/upload-multiple-files-in-django