# raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'image'

Tags: python, django

I have spent a LOT of time trying to resolve this- Read Django docs, consulted forms but not got anything satisfactory. So please be patient here with me. I am trying to do an upload of an Image file here from my html template
The file upload happens properly an d I am able to see the uploaded image file in the HTML.

In my views.py,

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import sys
from subprocess import run,PIPE
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def button(request):

    return render(request,'home.html')

def output(request):
    data=requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
    print(data.text)
    data=data.text
    return render(request,'home.html',{'data':data})

def external(request):
    inp= request.POST.get('param')
    image=request.FILES['image']
    print("image is ",image)
    fs=FileSystemStorage()
    filename=fs.save(image.name,image)
    fileurl=fs.open(filename)
    templateurl=fs.url(filename)
    print("file raw url",filename)
    print("file full url", fileurl)
    print("template url",templateurl)
    out= run([sys.executable,'D:/corona/Image Edit Html Button Run Python Script/Image Edit Html Button Run Python Script/test.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    image= run([sys.executable,'D:/corona/Image Edit Html Button Run Python Script/Image Edit Html Button Run Python Script/image.py',str(fileurl),str(filename)],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    print(out)
    print(image.stdout)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'data':out.stdout,'raw_url':templateurl,'edit_url':image.stdout})
```

In my home.html

```
home.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Python button script
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' %}'">Execute Script</button> <hr>
        {% if data %}

        {{data | safe}}

        {% endif %}
        <br><br>
        {% if raw_url or edit_url %}
        <span>
        RAW IMAGE:
        <img src={{raw_url}} height=500 width=500>
        PROCESSED IMAGE:
        <img src={{edit_url}} height=500 width=500>
        </span>

        {% endif %}

<br><br>
        <form action="/external/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
           Input Text:
            <input type="text" name="param" required><br><br>
           <br><br>

           <input type="file"name="image" id="image" required>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Execute External Python Script">

        </form>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you add a space between `type="file"` and `name="image"`, so `type="file" name="image"`.

Comment: it's the same error

Comment: image=request.FILES['image']
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'image'

Comment: This answer explains  how to upload multiple files in django maybe it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39526745/924300

Comment: thanks but i don't need this multiple upload