# Django: No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to implement multiple upload in my Django project. After doing similar as the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69333909/use-view-form-in-django-to-upload-a-multiple-files/69334720#69334720), I get **`No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.`** form error on submit(self.errors == `<ul class="errorlist"><li>image<ul class="errorlist"><li>No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.</li></ul></li></ul>`). What could be the problem? Could you help me please?

My **`models.py:`**

```
from PIL import Image as I

class Galery(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.userprofile.username + " - " + self.description


class Image(models.Model):
    galery = models.ForeignKey(Galery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img = I.open(self.image.name)
        img.resize(size=(300, 300))
        img.save(self.image.name)
        return super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My **`forms.py:`**

```
class CustomFileInput(forms.ClearableFileInput):
    allow_multiple_selected = True


class AddPhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Galery
        fields = ['description']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if commit:
            post = Galery.objects.create(
                user=self.instance,
                description=self.cleaned_data['description']
            )

            return post


class AddImagesForm(AddPhotoForm):
    image = forms.FileField(widget=CustomFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=True)

    class Meta(AddPhotoForm.Meta):
        fields = AddPhotoForm.Meta.fields + ['image']
```

My **`views.py:`**

```
class AddPhotoView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'add-photo.html'
    form_class = AddImagesForm
    success_url = 'my-space'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST,
                               request.FILES,
                               instance=request.user)
        photos = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        if photos:
            if form.is_valid():
                galery = form.save()
                for photo in photos:
                    Image.objects.create(galery=galery, image=photo)

                return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            messages.error(request, message='Upload at least one photo!')
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form})
```

My **`add-photo.html`**

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    {% render_field form.image name="image" %}
                </div><br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <ul class="list-group" id="list">
                    </ul>
                </div><br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <b>Add description: </b>
                </div><br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    {% render_field form.description class="form-control" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Write description here..." %}
                </div><br>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button style="width: 200px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I will be very grateful to anyone who can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Is `CustomUser` the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? If so, why is there a `UserProfile` model as well?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem yes, `CustomUser` is `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. `UserProfile` has 1to1 relationship with `CustomUser`. `UserProfile` contains username, first and last name, avatar etc...

Comment: but that seems quite strange: normally the entire point of creating a custom user model is *not* to create a `UserProfile`, since juggling with two models is always a bit tricky.

Comment: But regardless, can you `print(request.FILES)` and `print(request.POST)` in the `post` method, and share the output?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem `request.POST` - `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['f3Ov6qW7RkflsDoMcZys6Uhwj7ZRcudSRhrAXbr0s8I5u2yK8I2qaYnv1tPHDajV'], 'description': ['']}>
`, `request.FILES` - `<MultiValueDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: default(1).png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: bg.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
`. Hope it will make my problem clearer

Answer (score 0):

The modeling of the user logic seems a bit odd. You seem to use a `CustomUser`, which I assume is the user model, but if you make a custom user model, then it makes not much sense to have a separate `UserProfile` model: creating a custom user model is normally done *exactly* to avoid making an extra model.

But regardless, I think you are implementing *way* too much boilerplate code. As a consequence, the `AddPhotoForm` for example can not work with `commit=False`, and can no longer be used to *edit* a `Galery`.

The main problem is however likely the fact that Django's builtin `FileField` can *not* handle multiple files, or at least not by default. We have to create a form field that validates them if multiple ones are uploaded, for example with a form field [as specified in the documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files):

> ```
> class MultipleFileInput(forms.ClearableFileInput):
>     allow_multiple_selected = True
>
>
> class MultipleFileField(forms.FileField):
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         kwargs.setdefault("widget", MultipleFileInput())
>         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>
>     def clean(self, data, initial=None):
>         single_file_clean = super().clean
>         if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
>             result = [single_file_clean(d, initial) for d in data]
>         else:
>             result = single_file_clean(data, initial)
>         return result
> ```

The new `clean` method for the form field is necessary, since we thus will process *multiple* items.

Now we can make a `Galery` form with:

```
class AddPhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = MultipleFileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Galery
        fields = ['description']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        result = super().save(commit=commit)
        if commit:
            for image in self.cleaned_data['image']:
                Image(galery=result, image=image).save()
        return result
```

and now we can let the `CreateView` do its work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class AddPhotoView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'add-photo.html'
    form_class = AddImagesForm
    success_url = 'my-space'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, message='Upload at least one photo!')
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code to try if it works or not and I got `FileNotFoundError at /add-photo/` on submit. However my `request.POST` and `request.FILES` are the same (`request.FILES` - `<MultiValueDict: {'image': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: bg.jpg (image/jpeg)>`, `request.POST` - `<TemporaryUploadedFile: main_bg.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>` <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':['<my token>'], 'description': ['']}>).I'm getting this error wher pillow is trying to open my photo `fp = builtins.open(filename,"rb")` What could be the problem? P.S.: Sorry, I'm tired.

Comment: @party: `I.open(self.image.path)`.